# Draw an overlay to highlight the specific view of any shape in android

Tags: android, view, graphics

I have found the following libs on github to highlight the view.

1. [HighLightPro](https://github.com/hyy920109/HighLightPro)
2. [Balloon](https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon#balloonoverlay)

But the problem is that they have specific shapes like circel,react and oval that could be highlighted. Now I have a different shapes of view e.g pentagon. So all I need that some code or lib that can high light any view of any shape on screen.